# Persisting EF changes with constantly refreshed repository in WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

Working on a WPF application using MVVM and powered by Entity Framework. We were very keen to allow users to multi-window this app, for usability purposes. However, that has the potential to cause problems with EF. If we stick to the usual advice of creating one copy of the Repository per ViewModel and someone opens multiple windows of the same ViewModel, it could cause "multiple instances of  IEntityChangeTracker" errors.

Rather than go with a Singleton, which has its own problems, we solved this by putting a Refresh method on the repository that gets a fresh data context. Then we do things like this all over the shop:

```
using (IRepository r = Rep.Refresh())
{
    r.Update(CurrentCampaign);
    r.SaveChanges();
}
```

Which is mostly fine. However, it causes problems with maintaining state. If the context is refreshed while a user is working with an object, their changes will be lost.

I can see two ways round this, both of which have their own drawbacks.

- We call SaveChanges constantly. This has the potential to slow down the application with constant database calls. Plus there are occasions when we don't want to store incomplete objects.
- We copy EF objects into memory when loaded, have the user work with those, and then add a "Save" button which copies all the objects back to the EF object and saves. We could do this with an automapper, but is still seems unnecessary faff.

Is there another way?

Comment: I solved this in my current project by writing my own Repository class and using the second method. Anything that needs to change the repo must first obtain a Context object which locks a mutex in the ctor and unlocks it in Dispose(). This is one of the reasons I personally prefer the NHibernate-and-Fluent combo, it has much better out-of-the-box support for stuff like this

Comment: It sounds like you are using your DAO Objects in your ViewModel, which you should never do.

Answer (score 1):

I believe having the repository for accessing entity framework as a singleton may not always be wrong.

If you have a scenario were you have a client side repository, i.e. a repository which is part of the executable of the client application, i.e. is used by one client, then a singleton might be ok. Of course I would **not** use a singleton on the server side.

I asked Brian Noyes (Microsoft MVP) a similar question on a "MVVM" course on the pluralsight website.

I asked: *"What is the correct way to dispose of client services which are used in the view model?"*

And in his response he wrote: *"...most of my client services are Singletons anyway and live for the life of the app."*

In addition having a singleton does not prevent you from writing unit tests, as long as you have an interface for the singleton.

And if you use a dependency injection framework (see Marks comment), which is a good idea for itself, changing to singleton instantiation is just a matter of performing a small change in the setup of the injection container for the respective class.

Comment: If you're using dependency injection (and you should be) then you can scope them any way you like and even change it down the track if need be. For my own repositories I use singleton scoping for offline utilities, per-form scoping for WPF apps and per-request scoping for web apps...all using the same ORM code.

Comment: @Mark, than you, I added the hint for using a DI framework to my response